# ASP.NET Core MVC: Get values from Ajax, send to new View

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

This is similar to a previous issue that was resolved earlier. In this case, instead of rendering a table in the same view, I'd like to take the data retrieved and push to a new view:

1. Populate child area paths in a multiselect dropdown list
2. Select some of the items in the dropdown list
3. Take the selected items (as area path children) send back to controller
4. From controller use area paths as parameters to a method retrieving work items
5. Take workitem list and populate list in new view

Here is my view script

```
    function GetSelectedAreaPathChildren3() {
        alert("TEST1");
        var selectedAreaPathItems = '';
        $("#AreaPathMultiSelectDropdownList :selected").each(function () {
            selectedAreaPathItems += this.value + ";";
        });

        var selectedIterationPathItems = '';
        $("#IterationPathMultiSelectDropdownList :selected").each(function () {
            selectedIterationPathItems += this.value + ";";
        });

        console.log(selectedAreaPathItems);
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("WorkItemTable", "PbcAzureDevOps")',
            type: "POST",
            data: { selectedAreaPathItems, selectedIterationPathItems },
            success: function () {
                alert("BLAH!");
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my controller method

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> WorkItemTable(string selectedAreaPathItems, string selectedIterationPathItems)
    {
        //Get the retrieved work items
        List<WorkItemInfo> retrievedWorkItems =
            await GetAllSelectedWorkItems(selectedAreaPathItems, selectedIterationPathItems);

        return View(retrievedWorkItems);
    }
```

Expected result:

`retrievedWorkItems` is populated and sent to view ("WorkItemTable") -- after sending to view, "WorkItemTable is shown on screen

Actual result:

`retrievedWorkItems` is populated and sent to view ("WorkItemTable") -- after sending to view, "WorkItemTable is NOT SHOWN (i.e. WorkItemTable does not pop up)

I recognize from my research that I can't get the view to show up from the script and have also tried adding the following to the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("WorkItemTable", "PbcAzureDevOps", FormMethod.Post))
{
}
```

Can anyone help me to get the `WorkItemTable` to render... I can already see the data in the foreach part of the view, it just doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured a workaround... instead of pulling the selections from the dropdownlists using Ajax, I pulled the data from the dropdown via IFormCollection:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> WorkItemTable(IFormCollection collection)
    {
        List<string> selectedAreaPathItems = collection["apchildrenDropDown"].ToList();
        List<string> selectedIterationPathItems = collection["ipchildrenDropDown"].ToList();

        //Get the retrieved work items
        List<WorkItemInfo> retrievedWorkItems =
            await GetAllSelectedWorkItems(selectedAreaPathItems, selectedIterationPathItems);

        return View(retrievedWorkItems);
    }
```